# Scrolling Canvas in eclipse plugin doesnt work (blurrs)

Tags: java, canvas, scroll, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am developing a plugin for eclipse in which i want to draw some images into a custom view.
Creating the view and my layout works fine, but the scrolling in my canvas seems to be broken.
If I try to scroll over an image it looks like that: http://prntscr.com/xswwvw
It is just repeating small parts of the picture again instead of real scrolling.
I tried the same outside a plugin, i didnt get the Problem there.

I tried to search for a solution alot, but couldnt find one. Hopefully someone has an idea or some hints on how to solve this.
Here is my relevant Code:

```
public class FaultTreeView {
private Canvas canvas;
private ArrayList<FTShape> shapeList = new ArrayList<>();
private Point origin = new Point(0, 0);
private Image image;

@PostConstruct
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    container.setBackground(getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND));
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Composite comp = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
    addToolBar(comp);


    createCanvas(container);

    AndGate ag = new AndGate(canvas, 0, 0);
    this.image = ag.getImage();

    handleScrollBars();
    paintElementsInCanvas();
    

}
```

And here the methods:

```
public void addToolBar(Composite composite) {
    ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.VERTICAL);
    addDropdownMenu(toolbar);
}

public void createCanvas(Composite container) {
    this.canvas = new Canvas(container, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    this.canvas.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    this.canvas.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
}
```

For the ScrollBars i used some Code i found, but i added the *hBar.getPageIncrement() and *vBar.getPageIncrement() because otherwise it didnt let me scroll at all.

```
    private void handleScrollBars() {
     ScrollBar hBar = canvas.getHorizontalBar();
        hBar.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
          public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            int hSelection = hBar.getSelection()*hBar.getPageIncrement();
            int destX = -hSelection - origin.x;
            Rectangle rect = image.getBounds();
            canvas.scroll(destX, 0, 0, 0, rect.width, rect.height, false);
            origin.x = -hSelection;
          }
        });
        ScrollBar vBar = canvas.getVerticalBar();
        vBar.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
          public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            int vSelection = vBar.getSelection() * vBar.getPageIncrement();
            int destY = -vSelection - origin.y;
            Rectangle rect = image.getBounds();
            canvas.scroll(0, destY, 0, 0, rect.width, rect.height, false);
            origin.y = -vSelection;
          }
        });
}

public void paintElementsInCanvas() {
    canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            e.gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It is usually best to use a `ScrolledComposite` for the scrolling with a body just containing a `Label` with the image set in that.

Comment: Hi Greg, I am planning on adding alot of smaller pictures to the canvas, kind of a diagram containing multiple elements with a picture for each element with relative positions (Point(x,y)). I also want the user to be able to edit the diagram by hand, so i think i need a canvas, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `drawImage` call must use the `origin` to place the image correctly:

```java
e.gc.drawImage(image, origin.x, origin.y);
```

Also look at [SWT Snippet 48 scrolled canvas](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet48.java) for how to handle resize and scroll bar sizing correctly.

Comment: Got it working thanks to your advice. Thanks alot!